# couldn't install npm on ubuntu

Tags: package-management, nodejs, npm

Tried to install nodejs and npm on ubuntu 12.04. I googled and did it. Now, I could not install npm on machine.

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Which gives me this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I think nobody say, but `apt-get install npm` must be avoid (!). Check if `npm -v` is there before to try to install.... (read more below at @MarcoCerpi's answer )

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit system?  If so, it is not officially supported and you need to use a build from the node unofficial-builds web site.

Comment: Can't believe I'm still getting tripped over by this on Ubuntu 20.04...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by following [this documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html).

Pointers to remember to work with npm:

```
mkdir ~/nodejs/ && cd ~/nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
npm install
npm update
```

While developing applications, if nodejs needs any particular module then run

```
cd ~/nodejs
npm install modulename   #for example sendgrid
```

Sometimes, modules needs to install globally; then use

```
sudo npm install modulename -g"
```

To remove a module:

```
cd ~/nodejs
npm uninstall modulename          # if locally installed or 
sudo npm uninstall modulename -g  # if globally installed
```

`npm prune` helps to remove unmet dependencies

Comment: He cannot install npm men, how could he get to point 3?!

Answer (score 40):

This looks like you probably installed the [chris-lea node.js ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/) which is fine. However, you don't install npm from that ppa as it breaks the way debian packages work. Instead, just install `nodejs`. Once that's installed, run `npm -v` you should see it's now installed. If you didn't use the chris-lea ppa update your question on what webpage you Googled to find out how to install nodejs on Ubuntu.

Comment: How would he run "npm -v" if he cannot install npm...?

Comment: The "modern" `apt-get install nodejs` do also `npm` updated installation, so, I understand that `apt-get install  npm` must be avoided (!).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34244847/287948

Comment: I removed my PPA and I got ` npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed`

Answer (score 7):

Try installing NodeJs like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Since NodeJs installs node and npm

Comment: doesn't work with 16.04

Comment: no `npm` installed with this...

Answer (score 4):

Apt doesn't handle dependancy conflicts well, use snap or aptitude;

`sudo aptitude install npm`

I had to press "no" to the first solution it proposed, which did not include installing npm (that must be a bug in aptitude) then the second solution I pressed `yes` to
hTHen check npm was installed:

`npm --version`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is registry, execute this command,

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I work on this way, check it work for you

Comment: How would he run "npm config..." if he cannot install npm...?

Comment: When he runs `sudo apt-get install npm` command its give "unmet dependencies error".  I notice error npm already installed just need to set registry url.

Comment: Also worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install the PPA in order to get access to its contents:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo bash -
```

(This for version 9, which is the latest version at the time of writing).

And then

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Version conflict of manual installed npm and which comes with latest nodejs.

So you could try to remove nodejs, remove old npm and installed new nodejs again which comes with npm.

Answer (score 0):

it worked in my case.

first-:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```

then logout and come again and

```
 nvm install node
```

it will install npm .
hope it will help

Answer (score -2):

Installing nodejs will install npm, so just remove nodejs then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```