# Problem with installing nodejs

Tags: nodejs

First following link [couldn't install npm on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462337/couldnt-install-npm-on-ubuntu), I installed nodejs successfully, but then when I install npm, it gives error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
**npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed**
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@yatin-3000-N200:/home/yatin/Documents/installations# npm install
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install npm*
```

Also tell if there is some command from which dependencies also get installed automatically in Ubuntu without we caring for it.

Comment: The install command for npm is : `sudo apt update && sudo apt install npm`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!! I got answer at askUbuntu by lot of searching and struggle. First we need to install g++-4.8 which right way is given at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836858/upgrade-gcc-4-6-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-to-4-8-2 ,answer by JintoThomas, and then we can install nodejs following at [Ubuntu / Install NodeJS & npm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312536/ubuntu-install-nodejs-npm) , answer by Anton Dozortsev. And Thanks Parto but i tried it before, that not work for me. 
Then install less compiler(not for nodejs but if required) as

```
npm install -g less
```

Then final step is:
Because the command name of the node.js is nodejs (instead of node) on Ubuntu, when the installation is complete, you need to change this first line of lessc command. Open /usr/local/bin/lessc with your favorite text editor (with root privileges), and change the end of the first line from node to nodejs.

```
-#!/usr/bin/env node
+#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

'-' means in above remove it and '+' means add it

It may be possible that lessc is at some other localtion, check it by

```
which lessc
```

like for me it is at /usr/bin/lessc