# Ubuntu 20.04 should I downgrade libssl1.1 to libssl1.0 to install npm?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, lts, nodejs, npm

I'm trying to install npm and I found this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462337/couldnt-install-npm-on-ubuntu).
I run `aptitude install npm` and the suggested solution is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2) 
but 1.1.1g-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libnode-dev [Not Installed]                        
2)     libssl-dev [Not Installed]                         
3)     node-gyp [Not Installed]                           
4)     npm [Not Installed]                                



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

It's basically suggesting to downgrade, but what impact would that have on my system if I downgrade libssl1.1 to libssl1.0?

Edit: this problem resulted after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. [Dan Scally](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259238/846201)'s solution works and I also provided another option in the comments from launchpad where it's a bit more detailed for my particular situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have libssl installed through a PPA rather than the usual Ubuntu sources. If you do `apt search --names-only libssl` it should confirm that. The suggestion is to downgrade from g to f, not from 1.1 to 1.0: the changes between those versions are listed [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1g/CHANGES) and seem to me to fairly minor:

> Changes between 1.1.1f and 1.1.1g [21 Apr 2020]
>
> *) Fixed segmentation fault in SSL_check_chain()
> Server or client applications that call the SSL_check_chain() function
> during or after a TLS 1.3 handshake may crash due to a NULL pointer
> dereference as a result of incorrect handling of the
> "signature_algorithms_cert" TLS extension. The crash occurs if an invalid
> or unrecognised signature algorithm is received from the peer. This could
> be exploited by a malicious peer in a Denial of Service attack.
> (CVE-2020-1967)
> [Benjamin Kaduk]
>
> *) Added AES consttime code for no-asm configurations
> an optional constant time support for AES was added
> when building openssl for no-asm.
> Enable with: ./config no-asm -DOPENSSL_AES_CONST_TIME
> Disable with: ./config no-asm -DOPENSSL_NO_AES_CONST_TIME
> At this time this feature is by default disabled.
> It will be enabled by default in 3.0.
> [Bernd Edlinger]

Whether you're willing to accept that degraded capability for npm is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+question/691863

Answer (score 7):

### It is a dependency issue

Since `npm` depends on node-gyp which depends on libnode-dev which depends on libssl-dev and here is the issue, `libssl-dev` depends on `libssl1.1 versoin 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2` while you have a newer version `libssl1.1 version 1.1.1g-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`

So as workaround, you can go with [Dan Scally](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259238/846201)'s suggestion by downgrade from g to f as below

```
 sudo apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1f-1ubuntu2
```

Then you should be able to install npm

```
 sudo apt install npm
```

It is worked with me without issues.